# Can I FTP from Subversion?

Tags: svn, logging, deployment, ftp

I am using Subversion for source controlling my website project and I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to deploy using FTP from the SVN Log Messages dialogue? I'm basically shift selecting the revisions in the top pane and viewing the affected files in the bottom pane. With the affected file list I then individually select the items to deploy in my FTP client.

Would be really handy if a plugin existed (perhaps it does?) that allowed me to deploy via FTP directly from the bottom pane.

Does anybody know of such a plugin/extension that would allow me to achieve this?

[image: Subversion - Log Messages]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That'll be convenient, I was thinking the same thing. I might develop such features into my live html/css code editor: http://liveditor.com

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, not such a plugin exists.

But you can achieve similar results writing a post-commit hook on your subversion server, associated with some specific tag. See:
http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/svn2web.html

Or you could SSH to your hosting, do a SVN checkout of your project, and then do a SVN update each time you make changes.

If out don't have or want to SSH your server, you could set up a Netdrive to your web folder, and trick TortoiseSVN to make an update to that folder (have not tried this one, might be slow):
http://www.netdrive.net/download.html

Also you can set up lftp to just upload changed files from your local folder (this is what I do). It's not as efficient as svn (or rsync), but it's a lot better than just plain ftp:
http://sina.salek.ws/content/how-mirrorsync-remote-ftp-folder-local-folder

If you're on Windows, you can install Cygwin to get lftp.
http://www.cygwin.com

You could use rsync, but it's difficult to setup, I don't recommend it unless you have tons of things to synchronize, and don't mind messing withg and opening ports on your server.

There is also on windows a program that you can use to sync by FTP called Allway Sync. I've use it, it's ugly, tricky to set up, and slow, but works:
http://www.allwaysync.com/

You can pay for a hosted implementation of SVN-FTP sync:
http://svn2ftp.com/subversion-hosting-packages

Lastly, if you use FileZilla, you can select to just "overwrite files with earlier dates or different size" and upload the entire project, shouldn't be very slow.
http://filezilla-project.org